# How can I change full calendar language to Swedish?

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

I am facing a problem with changing the full calendar language to Swedish language. Is there any JS file for Swedish language among the 52 JS files of the full calendar or do I have to create it manually? If I have to create it manually then what's the procedure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Swedish you can use the file `sv.js` which is included with fullCalendar in the `locale` folder when you download the Zip file. `sv` is the ISO 639-1 code for Swedish. Each file is named by its ISO code, so you can identify the language it represents.

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ISO_639-1_codes for a full list of codes.

Answer (score 1):

This is the [locale file for Swedish language](https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar/blob/master/locale/sv.js). You can add it to your locale folder, import the sv.js file into the page and define the calendar this way:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            locale: 'sv' ...
        });
 });
```